# Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, update, subconsultas

intento actualizar una columna en base a una consulta en mysql

```
UPDATE documents SET total_free = (SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,'$[0].base')  from documents)
```

pero me da error

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

el
`SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,'$[0].base')  from documents` trae

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero actualizar la nueva columna total_free con ese resultado

la tabla es la siguiente

lo que realizo en mi subconsulta es acceder al valor de base del json  de la columna other_taxes *tipo (varchar que guarda un objeto tipo json )*
y ahora intento pasarlo a la columna total_free *tipo (decimal 15,2)*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,'$[0].base')  from documents trae una columna con datos numericos distintos

Comment: Intentaste colocar un LIMIT 1 en tu subconsulta? puedes colocar tu codigo completo?

Comment: No quiero limitarlo quiero pasar tal cual se presenta la consulta a la nueva columna

Comment: si toda la columna incluyendo los null

Comment: Pero alli traes 2 valores, necesitas los 2? puedes sumar ambos y asi tendrías  37.98 y solo te traería un solo resultado

Comment: mi objetivo no es ese, lo que quiero es pasar los resultados de la columna (consulta) a la columna total_free, estuve consultando y en lugar de total_free = utilizar total_free in pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Correcto, pero debes ser mas especifico, cuales resultados? todos? incluido los null?

Comment: @JosueVargas eso ya lo respondio.

Comment: @Wendy.S Los datos que traes, son de la misma tabla o de otra tabla ??? Podrías agregar esas tablas al post ???

Comment: son de la misma tabla

Comment: Perfecto, ahora tu pregunta empieza a verse más completa. Debajo te han dejado una posible solución, ve si te funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es bastante descriptivo: la subconsulta devuelve más de un resultado, lo cual no está permitido (porque esos múltiples resultados no se pueden asignar a un único campo).

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es actualizar todas los registros de la tabla `Documents` asignando el valor de `JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,'$[0].base')` al campo `total_free`. Si es eso lo que pretendes hacer, la consulta sería más sencilla que la que estás intentando:

```
UPDATE documents SET total_free = JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,'$[0].base')
```

¡Ojo! Asegúrate que quieres hacerlo en todos los registros, si no es así pon una cláusula WHERE que delimite los registros que quieres actualizar.

ACTUALIZACIÓN tras el comentario de Wendy:
Para convertir el valor a decimal, prueba con esto:

```
UPDATE documents SET total_free = CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,'$[0].base') AS DECIMAL(12,2))
```

Lógicamente, si tu campo `total_free`es de otro tipo diferente a DECIMAL(12,2), debes poner el tipo correcto

Comment: sin embargo los valores que le toma de JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,'$[0].base') son string y la nueva columna total_free es decimal de hasta 2 digitos entonces no guarda

Comment: @Wendy.S eso lo puedes arreglar con un CAST o un CONVERT. Deberías poner toda la información en la pregunta. Si pones los tipos de cada campo en la pregunta, puedo actualizar la respuesta para que cumpla tus requisitos.

Comment: muchas gracias eh logrado solucionar mi problema 

Comment: @Wendy.S recuerda marcar la respuesta